# Zigzag Linked List

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, while-loop, linked-list

I have written this function to zigzag a linkedlist. But its running for indefinite time. I checked the loop multiple times. Even for the example i tried doing the iteration on notebook but still i didn't figure out the problem why its running indefinitely.

```
# LinkedList() class is already defined in driver code
# zigzag takes a linkedlist instance and linkedlist.head 
def zigzag(ll, head):
    if head is None or head.next is None:
        return head

    curr = head
    while curr and curr.next and curr.next.next:
        next_node = curr.next
        after_node = curr.next.next
        temp = None
        if after_node.next:
            temp = after_node.next
        curr.next = after_node
        curr.next.next = next_node
        if temp:
            curr.next.next.next = temp
        curr = temp

    return ll


# << TEST >>
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ll = LinkedList()
    ll.insert_values([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    ll.Print()
    lln = zigzag(ll, ll.head)
    lln.Print()
```

expected output : 1 3 2 4 6 5

Comment: What is `LinkedList`?  You have not defined that class.

Comment: In any case, adding some simple `print()` statements in the loop to show the values of key variables (in this case, probably `curr`) should illuminate the problem.  This sort of basic debugging is a core skill, and you should definitely practice it.

Comment: I respect that but as a beginner in coding i am not aware of debugging and such stuffs. I am really disheartened by the StackOverflow community. Every time i ask a question i get downvote. I am beginner , i may ask silly questions. What is the problem in that. I should i get downvotes. Is this not a community that helps beginners or its just for the elite coders

Comment: At a minimum, you need to post a **complete** program, so that we may run it ourselves and see the results.  You did not do that.

Comment: _as a beginner in coding i am not aware of debugging_ Basically, it boils down to printing all of the important variables each time through the loop, and see if the printed values match what you expected.  Simple enough, eh?

Comment: _i may ask silly questions. What is the problem in that_ I suspect the downvote was not because the question was silly, but because it was **incomplete** as I mentioned above.

Comment: `LinkedList() class is already defined in driver code` This does not help us one bit.

Comment: I have no idea what a zigzag list is supposed to do. Can you explain why the desired output is as you put it? What is the rule that you need to implement? Sorry, but we cannot help you if you don't explain exactly what is needed, and provide the code for the class.

Comment: *"I am really disheartened..."*: we are volunteers willing to help. Don't take downvotes personally. They indicate that the question is not up to the standards, and in comments you can find out what the issues are and what you can do to improve the question. So far you have not addressed those comments.

Answer (score 0):

This line creates a loop in the list:

> curr.next.next.next = temp

Answer (score -2):

The code is correct, realization of List isn't correct(edit your question and load your List realization).

As I see you're beginner - don't cry about your questions gets downvoted - ask people why it gets downvoted.
And there is some tips for you, boy:

```
temp = None
    if after_node.next:
        temp = after_node.next
```

Here you anyway gonna assign None or node, so you could write just temp = after_node.next.

```
if temp:
        curr.next.next.next = temp
```

Same for this part.
And if you already created vars like next_node, after_node - push your mind from that vars.

```
curr.next = after_node
    curr.next.next = next_node
```

To:

```
curr.next = after_node
    after_node.next = next_node
```

Comment: "boy"? That is quite paternalizing.